# Error Redirecting to Another Page Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to redirect the page to  "Customer/MyReservation.aspx".
The below code redirects to "Customer/Reservation/MyReservation.aspx". How to redirect it properly.

`Response.Redirect("MyReservation.aspx")`

Answer (score 2):

You are in *Customer/Reservation* folder before redirecting your page to *MyReservation.aspx*

So first you have to go to your parent directory i.e., *Customer*

Use the following code

```
 Response.Redirect("../MyReservation.aspx");
```

Instead of `Response.Redirect("MyReservation.aspx");`